# How do I show the remaining seconds until my bootbox closes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootbox

I have my twitter BootBox open like this:

```
bootbox.dialog("{{$steps[0]}}");
```

after ten Seconds, I close my BootBox like this:

```
window.setTimeout(function(){
    bootbox.hideAll();
}, 10000);
```

Is it possible to show the remaining seconds until close in the BootBox?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a `div` to your message, like this:

```
bootbox.dialog("Your message <div id='SecondsRemaining'>10</div>");
```

Then update it using this function:

```
(function(){
    var remaining = 10; // Number of seconds
    var obj = document.getElementById("SecondsRemaining");
    var timeout = window.setInterval(function(){
        remaining--;
        if(remaining==0) {
            // Time is up, stop the timer and hide the bootbox
            window.clearInterval(timeout);
            bootbox.hideAll();
            return;
        }
        obj.innerHTML = remaining; // Update the value displayed
    }, 1000); // Decrease counter every second
})();
```

---

For bootbox 4+ the format has changed. The dialog should be created:

```
bootbox.dialog({ message: "Your message <div id='SecondsRemaining'>10</div>" });
```

Comment: @Scott I got this error: `Error: Please supply an object of options` You know how I can do to solve it? I'm using Bootbox v4.3

Comment: @alessadro I have updated the code. You need to provide the content as a `message` parameter. Hope that helps

Comment: @Scott can you provide the full code? I'm just confused where should I put the function :(

Comment: @AmirrezaNasiri That is the full code. Sorry not sure what you still need. If you are having an issue, perhaps start a question.